# Wine needs uninstall of nvidia-cuda-toolkit that I need too!

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, wine

When I want to install Wine, nvidia-cuda-toolkit has to be uninstalled. Is it really impossible to have both?

[image: Message]

Comment: What version of Wine and Ubuntu are you using.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04 and wine:"wine1.6 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4" (1.6.2 I think).

Comment: Please use the wine ppa.  It should be offering the 1.7.25 version and not have that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but once "ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa" added, it wants to install: wine 1:1.7.25-0ubuntu1~ppa4. Ok, that's fine but THE SAME message appears after hitting install! :(.

Comment: Then your case might be related to conflict between PPA. Do you have any other PPA added? Like the Xorg one?. To answer your question, it is possible to have both installed. I have them right now working together. In my case I have the 304 libopencl for example but I just updated to 343 with no problem. Try it again, if not send me an email to luisalvarado@ubuntu.com and I'll be glad to help you directly and find out what is happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank everybody who helped me to solve this problem.
Due to some other problems, I reinstalled Ubuntu and now it works.

I don't have the answer for those that have the same problem, unfortunately.

Thanks to everybody!